# sort command : -g versus -n flag

Tags: command-line

What's the difference between using the `sort` command with `-g` and `-n`?

I have tried both flags with `ls -la` and the output was identical.

The man-page says that `-g` "compares according to general numerical value" and `-n` "compares according to string numerical value" ?

I don't get what they mean there.

What does "general numerical value" mean? What does "string numerical value" mean?

Comment: I'm guessing but 'string numerical value' means that `0` and `00` or `09` and `9.00` are not treated as the same numbers.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255782/whats-the-difference-between-general-numeric-sort-and-numeric-sort-options

Comment: @Ron -g converts it and then compares floats. Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `sort` info page, sort `-g` is explained by these

```
‘-g’
‘--general-numeric-sort’
‘--sort=general-numeric’
     Sort numerically, converting a prefix of each line to a long
     double-precision floating point number.  *Note Floating point::.
     Do not report overflow, underflow, or conversion errors.  Use the
     following collating sequence:

        • Lines that do not start with numbers (all considered to be
          equal).
        • NaNs (“Not a Number” values, in IEEE floating point
          arithmetic) in a consistent but machine-dependent order.
        • Minus infinity.
        • Finite numbers in ascending numeric order (with -0 and +0
          equal).
        • Plus infinity.

     Use this option only if there is no alternative; it is much slower
     than ‘--numeric-sort’ (‘-n’) and it can lose information when
     converting to floating point.
```

`sort -n` is the natural sort we usually expect

```
‘-n’
‘--numeric-sort’
‘--sort=numeric’
     Sort numerically.  The number begins each line and consists of
     optional blanks, an optional ‘-’ sign, and zero or more digits
     possibly separated by thousands separators, optionally followed by
     a decimal-point character and zero or more digits.  An empty number
     is treated as ‘0’.  The ‘LC_NUMERIC’ locale specifies the
     decimal-point character and thousands separator.  By default a
     blank is a space or a tab, but the ‘LC_CTYPE’ locale can change
     this.

     Comparison is exact; there is no rounding error.

     Neither a leading ‘+’ nor exponential notation is recognized.  To
     compare such strings numerically, use the ‘--general-numeric-sort’
     (‘-g’) option.
```

Check [Steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/840812/61218) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 8):

The major difference is in the treatment of numbers that are in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). From `info sort`, when using the `-n` (numeric) sort

```
 Neither a leading `+' nor exponential notation is recognized.  To
 compare such strings numerically, use the `--general-numeric-sort'
 (`-g') option.
```

So, for example, given

```
$ cat file
+1.23e-1
1.23e-2
1.23e-3
1.23e4
1.23e+5
-1.23e6
```

then

```
$ sort -n file
-1.23e6
+1.23e-1
1.23e-2
1.23e-3
1.23e4
1.23e+5
```

whereas

```
$ sort -g file
-1.23e6
1.23e-3
1.23e-2
+1.23e-1
1.23e4
1.23e+5
```

Answer (score 3):

From [the `sort` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html):

> **‘-n’**
>   **‘--numeric-sort’**
>   **‘--sort=numeric’**
>
> Sort numerically. The number begins each line and consists of optional
>   blanks, an optional ‘-’ sign, and zero or more digits possibly
>   separated by thousands separators, optionally followed by a
>   decimal-point character and zero or more digits. An empty number is
>   treated as ‘0’. The `LC_NUMERIC` locale specifies the decimal-point
>   character and thousands separator. By default a blank is a space or a
>   tab, but the `LC_CTYPE` locale can change this.
>
> Comparison is exact; there is no rounding error.
>
> Neither a leading ‘+’ nor exponential notation is recognized. To
>   compare such strings numerically, use the `--general-numeric-sort`
>   (`-g`) option.

And;

> **‘-g’**
>   **‘--general-numeric-sort’**
>   **‘--sort=general-numeric’**
>
> Sort numerically, converting a prefix of each line to a long
>   double-precision floating point number. See [Floating point](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Floating-point.html#Floating-point). Do not
>   report overflow, underflow, or conversion errors. Use the following
>   collating sequence:
>
> - Lines that do not start with numbers (all considered to be equal).
> - NaNs (“Not a Number” values, in IEEE floating point arithmetic) in a consistent but machine-dependent order.
> - Minus infinity.
> - Finite numbers in ascending numeric order (with -0 and +0 equal).
> - Plus infinity.
>
> Use this option only if there is no alternative; it is much slower
>   than `--numeric-sort` (`-n`) and it can lose information when
>   converting to floating point.

So, it would *seem* that using `-g` could result in incorrect comparisons due to loss of precision, but for whatever reason, I can't produce such a result:

```
$ printf "%s\n" 1 1.23 1.234 1.2345 1.23456 1.234567 1.2345678 1.23456789 1.23456788888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888 1.23456788888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888878888888888 | sort -g
1
1.23
1.234
1.2345
1.23456
1.234567
1.2345678
1.23456788888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888878888888888
1.23456788888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
1.23456789
```

`sort -g` correctly places the second long fraction before the first, but the difference between the two is well beyond the precision from a `double`:

```
$ cat test.cpp  
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << (1.23456788888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888887888888888888888888888 < 1.23456788888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888) << endl;
    cout << (1.23456788888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888887888888888888888888888 > 1.23456788888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888) << endl;
}
$ make test     
g++     test.cpp   -o test
$ ./test        
0
0
```